# Emscripten installation on OS X

Tags: node.js, emscripten, asm.js

After passing the official tutorial first steps about downloading and installing of Emscripten, I faced with a problem, when tried to run `emcc -v`:

`WARNING:root:LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "7.0", expected "3.7")    WARNING:root:could not check fastcomp: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 
CRITICAL:root:Cannot find /usr/bin/llvm-link, check the paths in ~/.emscripten`

I'm on OS X El Capitain with NodeJS installed under `nvm`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution of the problem isn't clear for me, but I believe that the problem appears because of improper index of dependencies provided for `emsdk install` command.

Seems, that the problem is appearing for Emscripten version 1.36.

I've found and explained workaround in this public Gist: https://gist.github.com/vladignatyev/c200bdc06ffcf803ac6e

In short, you have to `emsdk install <here is dependencies>` like that `emsdk install sdk-1.35.0-64bit clang-e1.35.0-64bit emscripten-1.35.0` (explicitly select versions) instead of `emsdk install latest`.